# How to disable api level check for a specific code snippet

Tags: android

How to disable api level check for a specific code line that is giving the following error:

```
Call requires API level 14 (current min is 11): android.view.MenuItem#getActionProvider
```

this is the where it is giving the error **getActionProvider**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_server_status, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
    // Create the share Intent
    String playStoreLink = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" +
        getPackageName();
    String yourShareText = "Install this app " + playStoreLink;
    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
        .setType("text/plain").setText(yourShareText).getIntent();
    // Set the share Intent
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
    return true;
}
```

this is a menu that should work for all APIs 11+, if it is 14+ then the share button should work normally else i will hide that button from the menu or even load another menu.

I tried using **@TargetApi** but when I did that i tried to create another onCreateOptionsMenu but that is not possible to create two functions with the same name even when I used the **@TargetApi**

Even better is there a share button that works with API 11+?

Comment: inside of your menu , just check for the build target, if higher than 11 then use actionProvider else use another alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried using @TargetApi

That is the right answer.

> when I did that i tried to create another onCreateOptionsMenu

You do not need another `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method.

> Even better is there a share button that works with API 11+?

`android.widget.ShareActionProvider` works on API Level 14+. `android.support.v4.view.ShareActionProvider` works on API Level 4+, if are using the AppCompat action bar backport.

Note that there are virtually no devices running API Level 11-13, so worrying about 11 is not especially relevant today.

Comment: http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/107777-android-honeycomb-android-3-devices this shows some API level 11-13 Honeycomb devices

Comment: @Waqleh: That blog post is nearly three years old. The [Android device dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) shows that 0.1% of Android devices run API Level 13, and less than 0.1% of Android devices run API Levels 11 and 12.

Comment: if i use the @TargetApi will the menu even run on api level 11? this menu doesn't only have a share button, i need those buttons to work

Comment: @Waqleh - a September 2011 article is not relevant in January 2014.

Comment: @Waqleh: "if i use the TargetApi will the menu even run on api level 11?" -- no.

Comment: maybe I should stop support 11-13, ill try that